# как сделать программу цикличной Python?

Tags: python, циклы

```
print ('Приветствую вас, я программа по совету фарма маячков')

v = int(input('Про какие маячки вы хотите узнать? \n 1 Альфа \n 2 Бета \n 3 Гамма \n 4 закрыть программу \n '))
if v == 1:
  print('Альфа маячки: \n Лучше всего фармить на Темной Долине, в центре под башней в одном из домов \n(Примерное время фарма от 2 до 4 ночей) \n лучшее время фарма с 23:00-5:00 по МСК')    

if v == 2:
  print('Бета маячки: \n Лучше всего фармить на Армейских складах ближе к правой части вне группировки (Примерное время фарма 1-2 ночи)\n лучшее время фарма с 21:00-8:00 по МСК')

if v == 3:
  print('Гамма маячки: \n Лучше всего фармить на Окрестности Янова в самом начале локации. Лучше всего купить АФК Янов и там все выфармить (примерное время фарма от 2-3 часов) \n лучшее время фарма с 23:00-8:00 по МСК \n ')

if v == 4:
    exit()


while v < 4:
    v = int(input('Про какие маячки вы хотите узнать? \n 1 Альфа \n 2 Бета \n 3 Гамма \n 4 закрыть программу \n '))
if v == 1:
    print('Альфа маячки: \n Лучше всего фармить на Темной Долине, в центре под башней в одном из домов \n(Примерное время фарма от 2 до 4 ночей) \n лучшее время фарма с 23:00-5:00 по МСК')    

if v == 2:
    print('Бета маячки: \n Лучше всего фармить на Армейских складах ближе к правой части вне группировки (Примерное время фарма 1-2 ночи)\n лучшее время фарма с 21:00-8:00 по МСК')

if v == 3:
   print('Гамма маячки: \n Лучше всего фармить на Окрестности Янова в самом начале локации. Лучше всего купить АФК Янов и там все выфармить (примерное время фарма от 2-3 часов) \n лучшее время фарма с 23:00-8:00 по МСК \n ')

if v == 4:
    exit()
```

Comment: Искать тут не пробовали? Оберните весь код в while True:

Answer (score 0):

Вот реализация

```
while True:
   print ('Приветствую вас, я программа по совету фарма маячков')

   v = int(input('Про какие маячки вы хотите узнать? \n 1 Альфа \n 2 Бета \n 3 Гамма \n 4 закрыть программу \n '))
   if v == 1:
      print('Альфа маячки: \n Лучше всего фармить на Темной Долине, в центре под башней в одном из домов \n(Примерное время фарма от 2 до 4 ночей) \n лучшее время фарма с 23:00-5:00 по МСК')    

   if v == 2:
      print('Бета маячки: \n Лучше всего фармить на Армейских складах ближе к правой части вне группировки (Примерное время фарма 1-2 ночи)\n лучшее время фарма с 21:00-8:00 по МСК')

   if v == 3:
     print('Гамма маячки: \n Лучше всего фармить на Окрестности Янова в самом начале локации. Лучше всего купить АФК Янов и там все выфармить (примерное время фарма от 2-3 часов) \n лучшее время фарма с 23:00-8:00 по МСК \n ')

   if v == 4:
      exit()


   while v < 4:
       v = int(input('Про какие маячки вы хотите узнать? \n 1 Альфа \n 2 Бета \n 3 Гамма \n 4 закрыть программу \n '))
       if v == 1:
          print('Альфа маячки: \n Лучше всего фармить на Темной Долине, в центре под башней в одном из домов \n(Примерное время фарма от 2 до 4 ночей) \n лучшее время фарма с 23:00-5:00 по МСК')    

       if v == 2:
          print('Бета маячки: \n Лучше всего фармить на Армейских складах ближе к правой части вне группировки (Примерное время фарма 1-2 ночи)\n лучшее время фарма с 21:00-8:00 по МСК')

       if v == 3:
          print('Гамма маячки: \n Лучше всего фармить на Окрестности Янова в самом начале локации. Лучше всего купить АФК Янов и там все выфармить (примерное время фарма от 2-3 часов) \n лучшее время фарма с 23:00-8:00 по МСК \n ')

      if v == 4:
         exit()
```